# Integrate bower.json in jplayer

Tags: jquery

I had used jplayer in my website. but cause of some issues, got "shockwave flash" creash error in chrome browser. so i take updated jplayer from jplayer.org. In this new plugin theirs is "package.json", "bower.json" and "jplayer.jquery.json"  files available. i dont know how to use these files.So, can anyone know that how to use these files in html5, php site?